# Highlight a node connected with maximum links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have build a force directed graph for the sample data which I have

My code for this is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Adh5v751ehCX9t9iqhPX?p=preview)

[image]

My Question is at the time the graph loads I need to calculate the node which is connected with maximum nodes(i.e Music node which is connected with maximum number of nodes) and at the time of load It should be highlighted and display information.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: The force layout actually computes this for you -- the `.weight` property of each node contains the number of links. All you have to do is get the node with the highest `weight`.